NextJS App Router CORS error on POST request to api route
I'm getting a CORS error when doing a POST request to an api route. My next.config.mjs looks as follows:
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: [
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', value: 'true' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*' }, 
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', value: 'GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', value: 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

And my app/path/route.ts looks like this:
export async function POST() {
  // .....
  return NextResponse.json({ status: 'ok' })
}

What could be the issue?

It turns out a GET handler is also required on the route for the preflight request to work, after adding a GET method to my route the CORS error was gone.
export async function POST() {
  // .....
  return NextResponse.json({ status: 'ok' })
}

// GET just to return 200 status for preflight to work
export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ status: 'ok' })
}


